# How do you merge a commit that has been reverted?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-revert

I recently had a situation where I merged changes from a feature branch into my master branch and production branch. I then needed to remove the changes from my production branch so I used **git revert**.  I now need to merge those changes back into the production branch, but if I perform a *git merge sha1* I receive the message:

`Already up-to-date`

Can anyone help me with this?

**UPDATE**
So I wound up creating a branch off of my production branch, applying a diff from the files that I had reverted in that branch and then merging that change into production.  I don't like it, but it worked. I would still be interested in hearing if there is a way to use the same sha1.

Comment: Have you tried `git cherry-pick` instead?

Comment: Just tried it, cherry-pick didn't work either.

Comment: cherry-pick seems to work for me.  A slightly more manual equivalent would be `git format-patch $SHA1` -> writes 0001-description.patch.  Followed by `git am 0001-description.patch`, or  `git apply ...` and then commit, or even `patch -p1 ...` (at the top level of the repo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I now need to merge those changes back into the production branch

`git revert`, if done on the `production` branch, would have created a new commit canceling the one you wanted to remove.

Since that new commit is already on that branch ('`production`'), you cannot merge it.

If you meant "merge back to *`feature`* branch", then the merge you apply that new commit on the `feature` branch, removing the changes from the `feature` branch as well.

Comment: Hello VonC, I actually need to merge the commits in my master branch into my production branch, but since I've merged the feature branch into both production and master. The problem, I think is that the commit is in both master and production, but production has the "revert commit" which is newer so my changes aren't applied. Any ideas?

Comment: @akiladila "my changes"? Which changes? They are both in `master` and `prod`, so merging `master` to `prod` (even though `prod` has no one extra commit with the revert) will always produced an `Already up-to-date` message. Merging `prod` into `master`, though, should work just fine.